# What is the model key for an Errors object in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, validation, spring, spring-mvc

In my Spring MVC based web-app, I'm manually creating an Errors/BindingResult object after manually validating one of my domain objects. I can add my domain object into the Model by doing the obvious:

```
model.addAttribute("myObject", myObject);
```

After I do validation and have created an Errors/BindingResult object, under which key should I add that to the model?

Note: I can't use the automatic validation provided by @Valid and bind my domain and errors object at the method level. I really do need to know how to do this manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BindingResult` for a given model is added to the model map using keys constructed using a combination of `BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX` and the model name. if you have a dig through the source code (for example in `HandlerMethodInvoker.updateModelAttributes()`), you can see how it's used.

It's a bit risky, though, this implementation detail may change in future versions of Spring.

Comment: I take it they don't expose anything a little more fixed in the public API? Aware that this could change in the future (though probably unlikely).

Comment: @GaryF: Not that I could see, no. You're not really supposed to go poking about in there :)